# Add visible or hidden in an html element

Tags: jquery, prestashop

I am using doofinder under prestashop and I would like to modify its behavior in jquery. I saw that he added visible or hidden in his html template and I would like to be able to do it also in jquery but in the same way as him (see screen).
[image]

do you know how to do this in jquery?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `visible` is not a valid HTML5 Element attribute. `hidden` instead - *is*.

Answer (score 0):

For instance:
`document.querySelector(".df-fullscreen").setAttribute("visible", true);`

Answer (score 0):

`visible` **is not a valid HTML5 Element attribute**.
`hidden` instead *is* valid. And it's simple as

```
const myElement= document.querySelector("#myElement");
myElement.hidden = true;  // Use: true or false
```

Answer (score -1):

if you simply want to switch between the states visible and not-visible

```
let switchAttr = $('df-fullscreen').attr('visible') ? false : true;
$('df-fullscreen').attr('visible',switchAttr);
```

Comment: we have just global attribute ```hidden```  not Visible in html

Comment: you need to edit the answer , that allows me to remove downvote ok